# Android ImageView - Annoying Whitespace on the Right Side

Tags: android, layout, imageview, whitespace

So I'm trying to get used to Android and intending to create an app for the NASA's "Image of the Day" RSS feed, which essentially needs an image- and a couple of text views.
This is my current attempt at the layout (compiling for Android 4.3, if that should matter):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.headfirst.nasaiodt.Feed" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/testImgDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/test_img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/testTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/testDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/testContent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You'd think that's simple enough for its purposes, however, I just can't seem to get rid of a very resistant white bar on the right side of the picture:

[image: problem info]

Wasn't

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

in the ImageView supposed to take care of that?
(And no, it's not an eclipse glitch, it also shows up in the emulator.)

I'd appreciate your help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with `android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"`?

Comment: can you change scale type  android:scaleType="fitStart" to either fitxy or centercrop ..

Comment: Are you sure the whitespace is not part of the sample image? Your code looks fine to me. Also, have you tried a different `scaleType` to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try using scale type to fit X and Y coordinates. This will solve if its not a glitch.    


<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/testImgDescription"
            android:src="@drawable/test_img" />
```

Comment: Indeed, it does. Thank you. But why does fitStart cause the issue at all? The image should prove much larger than the screen.

Comment: i think image i not that much big coz you are using wrap_content for height. More over it entirely depends on you screen density.If you think image big enough try using scale type to cropCenter and see whats the result